# Convert to sRGB for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, photoshop, srgb

Should I select "Convert to sRGB" in Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator if I'm saving the image for the iPhone or iPad?

[Why You Should Probably Use sRGB](http://www.petapixel.com/2009/09/17/why-you-should-probably-use-srgb/) says you should use sRGB for web. But, what about for iPhone apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use sRGB on iOS for Colour Management (colour Management preserves the "author's intent" across different devices and environments).

iOS uses sRGB as the default colour space and so you should export content matched to the sRGB colour space.

There is an excellent WWDC 2012 video on this topic: "Session 523 - Best Practices for Color Management".  Login to developer.apple.com for the videos.

Answer (score -1):

The [iPhone 7](http://www.apple.com/iphone-7/specs/) uses a Wide Color display, based on [DCI-P3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3). It is capable of showing colors that can't be specified in the sRGB color space. If your images are particularly vivid you *may* get a benefit from using this color space, but you *must* embed a color profile into the image to be sure that iOS will utilize the colors correctly. The embedded profile should also ensure that the image is displayed properly on older iPhones.